# Menu Items not vertically aligned in select drop down menu of React Material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, web-frontend

In my react project, I have used the react material ui dropdown menu. But menu items were not vertically aligned. You can find the image below how it looks like.

[Image view of the menu items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUZx2.png)

So Here is my code.

```
 <div className="right">
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Grid container spacing={2} columnSpacing={5}>
                      <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <FormControl>
                          <FormLabel required="true" className="label">
                            Category
                          </FormLabel>
                          <Select
                            style={{
                              paddingBottom: '20px',
                              width: '220%',
                              height: '35px',
                            }}
                            id="demo-simple-select"
                            name="category"
                            value={values.category}
                            required
                            onChange={handleChange}
                          >
                            <MenuItem value="subscription">Subscription </MenuItem>
    
                            <MenuItem value="site">Site </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="payment">Payment </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="billing">Billing </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="other">Other </MenuItem>
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
```

Package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "project_syncfusion_dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.12.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2": "^19.4.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars": "^19.4.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts": "^19.4.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns": "^19.4.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids": "^19.4.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-inputs": "^19.4.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-kanban": "^19.4.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-popups": "^19.4.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-richtexteditor": "^19.4.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule": "^19.4.50",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^7.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.19"
  }
}
```

I am a beginner to front-end development and can someone help me to make the menu items vertically aligned?

Comment: FormLabel must be InputLabel. What do you have in "right" className ?

Comment: I'd recommend removing the styling and extraneous bits and try to get just the select working first. I was able to basically replicate your code in a sandbox and get it working fine (dropdown displaying as it should) sans the event handlers and styles.

Comment: @JB_DELR Using FormLabel instead of InputLabel wouldn't cause this issue. I've tested to confirm that's not it, as well.

Comment: Seems your class `'right'` is causing the items inside the form to float side by side.
Have a look in this sandbox which is working as expected https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-demo-material-ui-forked-tm2isq
If you are still not sure how to resolve the issue please provide the missing code from the class 'right'